# We divide interval $[0,1]$ into two parts. Find expected value of proportion of lenght of left interval to right, and of shorter to longer one.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let $k$ be lenght of left interval. $k\in[0,1]$ and right integral is of lenght $1-k$.
We define random variable $X$ in such a way as to obtain $P(X=\frac{k}{1-k})=k$. So $X$ represents ratio of lenghts of left to right interval.
Now expectancy value is $$\int_0^1k\frac{k}{1-k}dk$$ and it is divergent so expected value does not exist.

To obtain expected value of ratio of longer to shorter interval, we can assume that left one is shorter and then $k\in[0,1/2)$, so we have $$2\int_0^{1/2}k\frac{k}{1-k}dk$$

I have strong suspiction that something went wrong there.

Comment: How can $P(X=\frac k{1-k})=k$ if the variable is continuous?

Comment: You mean to say that the left interval is of length $k$ which is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, then the right interval is of length $1-k$, and then the density of $k$ is just $1$, so you have $\int_0^1 \frac{k}{1-k} dk$. This is indeed divergent, though. For the other one you have the same mistake, but you also have another question: is the density of the length of the shorter interval just $2$ on $[0,1/2]$ and zero elsewhere? Or could it be non-uniform? Either way this should be checked.

Comment: @DHMO Oh, right. So it would be correct if we change it to $P(X\leq\frac{k}{1-k})=k$ and change integrals appropriately. Then density is $1$ and it looks better.

Comment: Can you cite the original question?

Comment: Well, I'm little confused. I understand now that I picked density wrong. But what with changing second integral to $2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{x}{1-k}dk$. Will this give me correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
P(0 \le X \le \frac{k}{1-k}) &=& k \\
\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{k}{1-k}} f(x) \ \mathrm dx &=& k \\
\displaystyle \frac{f\left(\frac{k}{1-k}\right)}{(1-k)^2} &=& 1 \\
\displaystyle f\left(\frac{k}{1-k}\right) &=& (1-k)^2 \\
\displaystyle f(t) &=& \left(1-\dfrac{t}{1+t}\right)^2 \\
\displaystyle f(t) &=& \left(\dfrac{1}{1+t}\right)^2 \\
\end{array}$$

Therefore:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
E(x) &=& \displaystyle \int_0^\infty xf(x) \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac x {(1+x)^2} \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \left(\frac1{x+1}+\ln(x+1)\right)_0^\infty \\
&=& \displaystyle \text{diverges}
\end{array}$$

Indeed, I just ran a program in Python to verify that it diverges if we pick a point in $[0,1]$ uniformly.